# CSS Rotate flicker on top corner DIV

Tags: css, flicker, flip

https://jsfiddle.net/zeqnthe0/2/

```
.flipped-to-back
{
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(180deg);
            transform : rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```js
new Vue({
 data () {
   return {
               btnTicketingActive : false,
               btnEcosystemActive : false
    }
  },
  
          methods :
        {
            toggleBtnTicketing : function ()
            {
                this.btnTicketingActive = !this.btnTicketingActive;
            },

            toggleBtnEcosystem : function ()
            {
                this.btnEcosystemActive = !this.btnEcosystemActive;
            },

            checkBtnTicketing : function ()
            {
                if (this.btnTicketingActive)
                {
                    this.btnTicketingActive = !this.btnTicketingActive;
                }
            },

            checkBtnEcosystem : function ()
            {
                if (this.btnEcosystemActive)
                {
                    this.btnEcosystemActive = !this.btnEcosystemActive;
                }
            }
        },
        
            directives:
        {
            'click-outside':
            {
                bind: function (el, binding, vNode)
                {
                    // Provided expression must evaluate to a function.
                    if (typeof binding.value !== 'function')
                    {
                        const compName = vNode.context.name;
                        let warn       = `[Vue-click-outside:] provided expression '${binding.expression}' is not a function, but has to be`;

                        if  (compName)
                        {
                            warn += `Found in component '${compName}'`;
                        }

                        console.warn(warn);
                    }

                    // Define Handler and cache it on the element
                    const bubble  = binding.modifiers.bubble;
                    const handler = (e) =>
                    {
                        if (bubble || (!el.contains(e.target) && el !== e.target))
                        {
                            binding.value(e);
                        }
                    }

                    el.__vueClickOutside__ = handler;

                    // Add Event Listeners
                    document.addEventListener('click', handler);
                },

                // Remove Event Listeners
                unbind: function (el, binding)
                {
                    document.removeEventListener('click', el.__vueClickOutside__);

                    el.__vueClickOutside__ = null;
                }
            }
        }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
/* ------------------ */
    /* START - Intro Page */
    /* ------------------ */

    /*
    Primary 1 : #00796B;
            Lighter : #48A999
            Darker  : #004C40
            Fill    : #F5F5F6

    Primary 2 : #607D8B
            Lighter : #8EACBB
            Darker  : #34515E
            Fill    : #F5F5F6
            Accent  : #FF5722
    */

    /* ---------------------- */
    /* Primary Box Containers */
    /* ---------------------- */

    .btn-ecosystem, .btn-ticketing
    {
        height                   : 12.5rem;
        width                    : 100%;
        outline                  : none;
        border                   : 0;
        background-color         : unset;
        padding                  : 0;
        -webkit-transition       : 0.6s;
                transition       : 0.6s;
        -webkit-transform-style  : preserve-3d;
                transform-style  : preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-origin : 50% 50%;
                transform-origin : 50% 50%;
    }

    .flipped-to-back
    {
        -webkit-transform : rotateX(180deg);
                transform : rotateX(180deg);
    }

    /* ----- */
    /* Front */
    /* ----- */

    .btn-ticketing-front
    {
        width                       : 100%;
        height                      : 100%;
        background-color            : #607D8B;
        cursor                      : pointer;
        /*-webkit-backface-visibility : hidden;
                backface-visibility : hidden;*/
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color : transparent;
        -webkit-transition          : all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
                transition          : all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
        box-shadow                  : 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        display                     : flex;
        align-items                 : center; /* Align the inner div vertically */
        justify-content             : center; /* Align the inner div horizontally */
    }

    .btn-ticketing-front:hover
    {
        background-color : #34515E;
        box-shadow       : 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    .btn-ecosystem-front
    {
        width                       : 100%;
        height                      : 100%;
        background-color            : #00796B;
        cursor                      : pointer;
        -webkit-backface-visibility : hidden;
                backface-visibility : hidden;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color : transparent;
        -webkit-transition          : all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
                transition          : all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
        box-shadow                  : 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        display                     : flex;
        align-items                 : center; /* Align the inner div vertically */
        justify-content             : center; /* Align the inner div horizontally */
    }

    .btn-ecosystem-front:hover
    {
        background-color : #004C40;
        box-shadow       : 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }

    .flipped-to-back .btn-ticketing-front, .flipped-to-back .btn-ecosystem-front
    {
        pointer-events : none;
    }

    /* ---- */
    /* Back */
    /* ---- */

    .btn-ticketing-back
    {
        position                    : absolute;
        width                       : 100%;
        height                      : 100%;
        background-color            : #607D8B;
        cursor                      : pointer;
        -webkit-transform           : translateZ(-2px) rotateX(180deg);
                transform           : translateZ(-2px) rotateX(180deg);
        overflow                    : hidden;
        box-shadow                  : 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        -webkit-backface-visibility : hidden;
                backface-visibility : hidden;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color : transparent;
        display                     : flex;
        align-items                 : center; /* Align the inner div vertically */
        justify-content             : center; /* Align the inner div horizontally */
    }

    .btn-ecosystem-back
    {
        position                    : absolute;
        width                       : 100%;
        height                      : 100%;
        background-color            : #00796B;
        cursor                      : pointer;
        -webkit-transform           : translateZ(-2px) rotateX(180deg);
                transform           : translateZ(-2px) rotateX(180deg);
        overflow                    : hidden;
        box-shadow                  : 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        -webkit-backface-visibility : hidden;
                backface-visibility : hidden;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color : transparent;
        display                     : flex;
        align-items                 : center; /* Align the inner div vertically */
        justify-content             : center; /* Align the inner div horizontally */
    }

    /* ------------- */
    /* Button Corner */
    /* ------------- */

    .btn-corner
    {
        position            : absolute;
        height              : 4rem;
        width               : 4rem;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                backface-visibility : hidden;
    }

    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner
    {
        border-right        : 1.1rem solid #8EACBB;
        border-top          : 1.1rem solid #8EACBB;
    }

    .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner
    {
        border-right        : 1.1rem solid #48A999;
        border-top          : 1.1rem solid #48A999;
    }

    .btn-ticketing:hover .btn-corner
    {
        border-right       : 1.1rem solid #8EACBB;
        border-top         : 1.1rem solid #8EACBB;
        -webkit-transition : 0.2s;
        -moz-transition    : 0.2s;
        transition         : 0.2s;
    }

    .btn-ecosystem:hover .btn-corner
    {
        border-right       : 1.1rem solid #48A999;
        border-top         : 1.1rem solid #48A999;
        -webkit-transition : 0.2s;
        -moz-transition    : 0.2s;
        transition         : 0.2s;
    }

    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(1), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(1),
    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(5), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(5)
    {
        right               : -0.5rem;
        top                 : -0.5rem;
    }

    .btn-ticketing:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(1)
    {
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
        right        : 2.5rem;
        top          : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
    }

    .btn-ecosystem:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(1)
    {
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
        right        : 2.5rem;
        top          : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
    }

    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(2), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(2),
    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(6), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(6)
    {
        left                : -0.5rem;
        top                 : -0.5rem;
        -webkit-transform   : rotateZ(-90deg);
                transform   : rotateZ(-90deg);
    }

    .btn-ticketing:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(2)
    {
        left         : 2.5rem;
        top          : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
    }

    .btn-ecosystem:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(2)
    {
        left         : 2.5rem;
        top          : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
    }

    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(3), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(3),
    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(7), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(7)
    {
        bottom              : -0.5rem;
        left                : -0.5rem;
        -webkit-transform   : rotateZ(180deg);
                transform   : rotateZ(180deg);
    }

    .btn-ticketing:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(3)
    {
        bottom       : 2.5rem;
        left         : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
    }

    .btn-ecosystem:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(3)
    {
        bottom       : 2.5rem;
        left         : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
    }

    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(4), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(4),
    .btn-ticketing .btn-corner:nth-of-type(8), .btn-ecosystem .btn-corner:nth-of-type(8)
    {
        bottom              : -0.5rem;
        right               : -0.5rem;
        -webkit-transform   : rotateZ(90deg);
                transform   : rotateZ(90deg);
    }

    .btn-ticketing:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(4)
    {
        bottom       : 2.5rem;
        right        : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #607D8B;
    }

    .btn-ecosystem:hover .btn-corner:nth-of-type(4)
    {
        bottom       : 2.5rem;
        right        : 2.5rem;
        width        : 2rem;
        height       : 2rem;
        border-right : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
        border-top   : 0.4rem solid #00796B;
    }

    /* ------------ */
    /* H2 Card Text */
    /* ------------ */

    .btn-ticketing-front h2, .btn-ecosystem-front h2
    {
        font-family        : Bree Serif;
        letter-spacing     : 1.2rem;
        color              : #FFF;
        text-align         : center;

        -webkit-transition : 0.2s;
        -moz-transition    : 0.2s;

  .btn-ticketing-front:hover h2, .btn-ecosystem-front:hover h2
    {
        font-size          : 2.5rem;
        font-weight        : bold;
        letter-spacing     : 0.3rem;
        -webkit-transition : 0.2s;
        -moz-transition    : 0.2s;
        transition         : 0.2s;
    }

    /* ------------------ */
    /*  END - Intro Page  */
    /* ------------------ */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <button class="btn-ticketing" @click="toggleBtnTicketing" v-bind:class="{ 'flipped-to-back' : btnTicketingActive }" v-click-outside="checkBtnTicketing">
                        <div class="btn-ticketing-back">
                            <p>Btn 1 Back</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-ticketing-front">
                            <h2 class="my-auto">Btn 1 Front</h2>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                            <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        </div>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <button class="btn-ecosystem" @click="toggleBtnEcosystem" v-bind:class="{ 'flipped-to-back' : btnEcosystemActive }" v-click-outside="checkBtnEcosystem">
                    <div class="btn-ecosystem-back">
                        <p>Btn 2 Back</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-ecosystem-front">
                        <h2>Btn 2 Front</h2>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                        <div class="btn-corner"></div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked and flipped to the back you can see the top two corners immediately get clipped by the button then disappear correctly when the animation is complete. When clicked again, the button flips back around and, again, the top two corners are clipped temporarily by the button until the animation stops. Meanwhile the bottom corners work fine it seems.

JSFiddle makes this effect look like a flicker but in Chrome it happens slowly and it is very pronounced.

I need the corners to appear one with the front layer of the button.

Any ideas?

Comment: No clue if this is a fruitful line of inquiry or not, but have you considered that in the repainting, the z-index might not be obvious to the browser? Could help to try being explicit about what should render in front of what.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I've tried adding z-index's to the front/back and corner layers accordingly and it didn't help.